# How to check a random number created from another class in java every time my program is executed

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


class createacc extends Thread{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    createacc(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Bank.\nDo you want to make us your life partner ?(Yes/No)");
        String decision;
        decision=sc.nextLine();
        switch (decision){
            case "Yes":
                break;
            case "No":
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input. Check th format in which yes and no are to be written ");
                System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter your full name ");
        String name= sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your full address ");
        String adress= sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please wait while we are processing with your account");
        try{Thread.sleep(7000);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}
        System.out.println("This is our recorded information:\nYour name:\t"+name.toUpperCase()+"\nYour address:\t"+adress.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("Please wait while we are generating your Account number");
        try{Thread.sleep(14000);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}
        int min=5000;
        int max=10000000;
        double a=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        System.out.println("Your account id is "+a+"\n Keep it carefully as you may need this for logging into your account in future");
        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting us");System.exit(0);

    }
}
 class withdrawal extends createacc{
    withdrawal(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to your life partner");

    }
}
class deposit extends  withdrawal{
    deposit(){

    }
}

public class bankmanager {
    public static void main(String [] agrs){
        createacc c=new createacc();
    }



}
```

I want that whenever my withdrawal and deposit class is executed ,it will demand for the id generated by random() method and if it matches i.e. if that number was executed previously **in that particular** device, it will give access to the rest of the code in the class.
In other words I want to create something like what we call *localstorage* in javascript.

Comment: Separate account information from the creation of the account information.  In other words, create an Account class and an AccountCreation class.  The Account class should be a plain Java getter / setter class.  The AccountCreation class should implement Runnable instead of extending Thread.  Your localstorage would be class variables in the Account class that are initialized in the class constructor.